# Yii2 adding multiple images in detail view

Tags: image, yii2, yii2-basic-app, detailview

In yii2 Detail how can I add multiple images. I am able to add only 1 image for a single row.. I want multiple images to be displayed.

```
[
                    'label' => 'Class Labels',
                    'format' => 'image',
                    'value' =>'/web/images/transport_class/class8.jpg'.','.'/web/images/transport_class/class8.jpg',
            ],
```

As of now tried this not working... But if leave with single image it works. any solution for this problem??
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

```
'value' => function($model){
    return Html::img('img1.png').Html::img('img2.png');
},
'format'=>'raw',
```

Answer (score 0):

just use a function returning a string value, or a static helper. for images you could return:

```
'value' => \yii\helpers\Html::img(['@web/images/transport_class8.jpg'])
```

---

or

```
class MyHelper
{
    public static function myImages($model)
    {
            $images = [];
            if ($model->class1)
                    $images[] = Html::img('class1.jpg');
            if ($model->class8)
                    $images[] = Html::img('class8.jpg');
            return implode(' ', $images); // return your html code here
    }
}
```

---

```
'value' => MyHelper::myImages($model)
```